# How to check when shipping methods was loaded in checkout in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

At checkout the shipping methods are loaded by AJAX. After loaded I need to call a new .js method.

How can I do this?

Thank You!

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?